# Astronomy detective question: what part of the sky are these photos of? What are a few of the stars?

Tags: photography, identify-this-object

The 9to5Google article [Exclusive: Official Pixel 4 camera samples show astrophotography, selfies, more [Gallery]](https://9to5google.com/2019/10/02/exclusive-pixel-4-camera-samples/) shows some surprisingly nice (at least to me) photos of the Milky Way.

I've asked [Milky Way with a cell phone, how is this possible?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/112389/50110) in Photography SE, but here I'd like to double check the scale and FOV of these images.

I'd like to establish the FOV and scale in pixels per degree for these images, so I need to know what part of the sky are these photos of and what are a few of the stars? I understand that a wide field view with a cell phone camera may have some distortion so I'll do the corners separately from the center.

I wanted to ask for an estimate of the latitude. I guess that's only possible if we assume the bottom edge is parallel to the horizon.

---

click for full size:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Astrometry.net](http://nova.astrometry.net/) successfully plate-solved both images.

The [first image](http://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/3099418) is of the Cygnus region with north to the left.
It is 73° wide and 55° high, with 65 arcseconds per pixel or 55 pixels per degree.
Bright stars include Deneb (α Cyg) left of center and Altair (α Aql) at upper right.

The [second image](http://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/3099463) is of the Sagittarius region with north up.
It is 37° wide and 66° high, with 80 arcseconds per pixel or 45 pixels per degree.
The bright object left of center is Saturn, which was at that position around 2019-07-29.

Comment: This is *really great*, thank you! fyi I've just asked [How (the heck) does Astronetry.net work?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33575/7982)